# What book had the Norse gods in a nuclear war against ice giants?

Tags: story-identification, books, thor-mythology

The story is that a scientist or engineer is kidnapped by the Norse gods to help them. A tree that gave fruit that kept them powerful was dying, and the ice giants were on the war path. He used gnomes that could produce anything to build a nuclear device, and dropped it on the giants from a flying chariot. He also used some basic knowledge of trees to save the tree and was allowed to eat of its fruit.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting story Gunner.

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211298/old-sci-fi-mag-short-story-nukes-heavy-artillery-introduced-to-and-used-by-nors (which is newer but has a definite confirmation for the same answer)

Answer (score 10):

I believe you are referring to "Day of the Giants" by Lester del Rey. It was originally published as "When the World Tottered" in the December 1950 issue of Fantastic Adventures before being published as a novel in 1959.

[Lester Del Rey Wiki site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lester_del_Rey)

[Cover of book and a brief description](http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/d/lester-del-rey/day-of-giants.htm)

[Additional book Review](http://yellowedandcreased.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/day-of-the-giants-lester-del-rey/)

Comment: I think that's it. Thanks. Now I have to get a copy of it. For some reason that story has been in my head for the last week and my google-fu has failed me.